# Win32 OpenFileDialog Does Not Filter *.DOCX Shortcuts

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I could do this on several different computers with Windows 7 SP1.

This can be duplicated in Notepad (or any other app that uses `OpenFileDialog`)

1. Create a shortcut to a DOCX
2. Launch notepad
3. File, Open
4. Filter on *.txt
5. Browse to location of *.docx shortcut

*.docx is the only shortcut extension I can find that does not filter. So far my only workaround is for my application to check the file extension after the user selects a file.

Is there some way to make `OpenFileDialog` filter out *.docx.lnk files as the user might expect it to?

Why are only Office file extensions affected?

Comment: Actually is all Office 2007+ files.  So .pptx and whatever.  Checked against random 4 letter extensions are hidden.

Comment: It appears that it happens no matter what the filter extension is - it's not just *.txt.

Comment: Sorry not a a programming question.  More of a reminder to always validate input.  My app just got bit on this one.

Comment: Shortcuts always have a .lnk extension, it's just hidden from view in Explorer

Comment: This is a good question, except that you didn't actually ask one.  I've added what I think the implicit questions are, but please edit it again if you disagree.

Comment: Interestingly, it's only the shortcut, not the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Only shortcuts to Office 2007+ documents are affected.
(Shortcuts actually have a .lnk extension that is hidden by the shell, i.e. Windows Explorer)

FindFirstFile does *not* find these files when the mask "*.txt" is specified, so this is something the shell does.

[You could attempt to disable respective shell plugins](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html#DownloadLinks) to determine which plugin is responsible for that behavior (to be safe: disable the plugins, kill and restart explorer through task manager, then restart your process before testing again).

I've checked the most obvious candidates, couldn't find any.

---

Programming advice: Verify your input. In your case, this is the file content, not the file extension!

I can specify any fiel in the Open dialog, even if you limit the mask.
I can save my text file as "really.important" and still expect to open it in your application.
I can save my word file as "really a word document.txt", open this in your application and at least expect you to not crash-